# WSO2 Registry Tool Feedback

Tags: repository, registry, wso2, soa

I am part of Enterprise Architect Team and currently evaluating WSO2 Registry Tool for future use.

Can anyone help me on below questions?

1. Any organisation using UKWSO2 Registry Tool ?
2. Feedback on tool (mainly customisation, ease of use, simple configurations etc.)
3. Support Cost
4. Implementation Cost if required.

Comment: Did you mean the WSO2 Governance Registry?

Comment: This question is not a fit for Stack Overflow as it is very opinion based. I have used the Governance Registry and it was pretty easy to use etc but your mileage might vary.

Answer (score 0):

IBM WSRR , Fuse Service Mix overwieghed WSO2 sometimes . IMHO , if you have a centralised ESB , it makes sense to go with the same vendor . If its a federated ESB structure , we need to ask who is the major stakeholder using this - if its just business , a sharedpoint might be enough as well .